# Is there an existing protocol for GPS over network?

Tags: networking, gps, protocols

I'm looking to share a GPS signal over Ethernet. I can just bundle the data in a UDP message and be done with it, but I was wondering if there were any existing (open or otherwise) protocols for doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "share a GPS signal over Ethernet?" Do you want to send the GPS data across the network or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: I want to share the coordinates and time to other devices on a local network. The time will be shared using NTP, and I was wondering if there was anything existing that I could use for the gps coordinates...

Answer (score 0):

What you mean to ask is if there are any existing protocols for communicating GPS coordinates over a TCP/IP network. "ethernet" and "gps signal" don't necessarily have the meaning you're looking for.

Do I know of any? No. But I would recommend you use TCP sockets instead of UDP.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **NMEA 0183** format which is not a format tied to a medium but is or was mostly used over serial.  Use this [NMEA sentence parser builder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/279647/NMEA-sentence-parser-builder/)
to build NMEA sentences and stream them over a TCP socket.